# extract value inside <strong> tag

Tags: php, regex

I have a string and I wanted to extract the value in between the

```
<p><strong>Polka Longsleeve</strong><br />Twistcone<br />Bust 95<br />Length 60<br />Po Bkk 04-10Nov <br />Closed Po 10 Nov (11AM On time)</p>
```

I've been trying to use strip_tag but I can't find a specific tag only, in this case strong. So what is the best solution for this?

Comment: have you considered using an HTML parser for this task?

Answer (score 2):

You can use DOM to extract the contents between the tag ...

```
$doc = DOMDocument::loadHTML('
     <p><strong>Polka Longsleeve</strong><br />Twistcone<br />Bust 95<br />
     Length 60<br />Po Bkk 04-10Nov <br />Closed Po 10 Nov (11AM On time)</p>
');

$tag = $doc->getElementsByTagName('strong');
echo $tag->item(0)->nodeValue; //=> "Polka Longsleeve"
```

<kbd>[**Working Demo**](https://eval.in/219379)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Although the question is tagged with regex, and experienced people have answered it. I have heard parsing HTML with regex is not a good idea. PHP as you know, does support DOM parsing now, So you could try out,

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($str);
$str = $dom->getElementsByTagName('strong')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

might work, I haven't tested though, or maybe `getTextBetweenTags`.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $pos=strpos($str,'<strong>'); 
  $end=strpos($str,'</strong>');
  echo substr($str,$pos+8,$end);
```